# Why is awakeFromNib not called when the view is visited again?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawrect

I would like to know if there is a method equivalent to `awakeFromNib`.

My app has 2 views and the 2nd view has a subclass (`UIView`) which I use to draw.

I use a timer which is called from `awakeFromNib` in order to animate the drawing.

```
- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:selfselector:@selector(ReDraw) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void) ReDraw
{
    i++;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Now when i go back to my first view and come back to this view the drawing is still on (awakeFromNib is not called again).

The timer doesn't stop when i go back to the first view. I want the timer to stop when i go back and the drawing to restart when i visit the second view again.

The methods `viewdidLoad` and `initWithFrame:` do not work inside the subclass.

Comment: UIViews don't even have the viewDidLoad methods only UIViewControllers. What about viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear? I mean when you show other views you can just stop the timer there.

Comment: It does not have viewWillAppear and viewWillDisappear

Comment: Of what kind of class is "it"?

Comment: Its an Objective C class which is a subclass of UIView. The method initWithFrame was there by default along with drawRect but is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awakeFromNib`, `viewdidLoad` and `initWithFrame` are all called during the initialization phase of the object. If the object is already created, those methods will not be called again. You can force a view to draw itself by using the `setNeedsDisplay` method of the view.

Comment: So how do i stop the timer when i go back to my first view and fire it from scratch again when i go to the view again?

Comment: You you create your timer, retain it as in instance variable in a controller class (UIViewController perhaps). When you switch a the view invalidate your timer and then start it again if you have to.

Comment: ok... but i cannot start it again since i use awakeFromNib to use the timer first time. I cannot even call a method inside the class(with drawRect method) which is a subclass of UIview from another class.